# Bluetooth sending to a MAC address

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to send some file via bluetooth to another device which is not discoverable. I have its MAC address.

I couldn't find any code/tutorial/help regarding this.

I pieced out a few things together from the documentation.

There is a bluetoothAdapter class which has a function,

`getRemoteDevice(String address)`

this will return a `BluetoothDevice` object to me. Then I can use

`BluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()` to create a socket and call

`connect()` to attempt a connection to the remote device.

This however is not establishing a connection between the devices. (If I am doing it correctly.)

Can someone highlight or provide a code snippet of how to actually accomplish this connection and then send some file over?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure is correct - it should connect.

What error message are you seeing when connection fails ? Are you ensuring that the other device is waiting for the connection ? i.e by doing the equivalent of listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord ?

Comment: No I did not. That is not what I want to do. I want to be able to send to any mobile whose MAC address I have. If I have to setup a receiver in the other phone, it sorts of defeats the purpose. I could have used the famous Bluetooth Chat Example and modified it to work. I want to be able to send to any mobile whose bluetooth MAC address I have. Any ideas?

Comment: The normal bluetooth also connects two devices irrespective of make, right? IT just scans for the MAC and then connects, I already have the MAC. How do I use the same thing just with an already obtained MAC?